# Return Max Value of range that is determined by an Index & Match lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, excel-2010, excel-match

I need a cell to display the max value of a range who's row is defined by an index and match formula. I know this will be an array function but I'm struggling to get the syntax right. Here is what my data looks like. I have it laid out with Column Letters and Row Numbers like Excel.

Using the Table Below as reference, in a second table. When I enter `b` in cell `A1` and `y` in column `B1`, the formula in cell `C1` should return the value `35` because `35` is the maximum value in columns `C:F` on the row determined by `A1` and `B1` using `INDEX` and `MATCH`

Table 1.

```
     A      B      C     D     E     F
1    a      x      25    6     23    11
2    a      y      39    15    42    19
3    b      x      28    34    51    24
4    b      y      27    19    15    35
5    b      z      38    26    12    18
6    c      x      12    19    22    15
```

Now... What I want to do, is to create a formula that finds the max of columns `C` through `F` in the row that matches the values in `A` and `B` that are given in a separate table. For this example we will write the formula in cell `C1`. The formula should take the maximum of `C` through `F` based on a match of column `A = b` and column `B = y` (which the formula tells us is row `4`). The value I want in this case would be `35` because it is the max of the 4 columns (`C:F`) on row `4`.

This is what my second table should look like with the formula being in row `C`

Table 2.

```
     A      B      C
1    b      y      35
2    a      x      25
3    b      z      38
4    c      x      22
```

I tried this: (the formula is in table 2 so it is not explicitly declared in the match portion of the formula. You'll also have to be familiar with tables in excel to get it)

```
 =INDEX(MAX(Table1[C]:Table1[F]),MATCH([@A]&[@B],Table1[A]&Table1[B],0))
```

I then wrap it with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>Enter</kbd>  to Array it.

The problem seems to come when I put the `MAX` function inside the array portion of the `INDEX`. Are there any ways around this? perhaps I should be using a completely different set of functions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need an index match formula. You can use this array formula. You have to press <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after you enter the formula.

```
=MAX(IF((A1:A6=A10)*(B1:B6=B10),C1:F6))
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: You can use INDEX and MATCH if you want. This one is longer than Sid's suggestion but doesn't need CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER....`=MAX(INDEX(C1:F6,MATCH(1,INDEX((A1:A6=A10)*(B1:B6=B10),0),0),0))`

Comment: @barryhoudini - `=MAX(IF(MMULT((A1:A6=A10)*(B1:B6=B10),1),C1:F6))` also works. `MMULT(...,1)` seems to work more generally than `INDEX(...,0)` for making formulas non-array entry.

Comment: Late to the party - This is great! I was wondering though if I can expand this as many times needed, or if this method only works well with say two conditions? (Basically, could I do a formula like this: `=MAX(IF((A1:A6=A10)*(B1:B6=B10)*(C1:C6=C10)*(D1:D6=D10)*(E1:E6=E10),C1:F6))`?)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the match-type to 1 when you are looking for the greatest value or to -1 when looking for the smallest value.