# Return multiple matches when range is dynamic

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column which is a dynamic named range:

```
A
A
B
C
A
```

How can I apply a `MATCH` or other formula which returns the row or cell address of all `A` values in the dynamic named range?

A dynamic named range is used so all row or address of `A` values can automatically appear as a spill rather than having to drag down the formula.

I have seen numerous formulas in this structure:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$8, SMALL(IF($A$11=$A$2:$A$8, ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW(1:1)))
```

However, most of these seem to return the first instance (row or cell address of the first match) and requires the formula to be dragged down manually rather than a spill, which is more preferable.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FILTER:

```
 =FILTER(ROW(A1:A5),A1:A5=C1)
```

This will return the Row number everywhere they match.

[image]

From there it is pretty easy to include that in INDEX:

```
=INDEX(B:B,FILTER(ROW(A1:A5),A1:A5=C1))
```

[image]

If you do the full column in the index, you do not need the `ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1` as returning the actual row instead of relative works just fine.

[image]

Comment: OMG - that's just great.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `=SORT(ROW($A$1:$A$5)/($A$1:$A$5=$C$1))`. This will get you the matches of a value in C1 with a spill formula, leaving behind #DIV/0 errors

See example below:
[image]

Other answers that you might be able to take ideas from are here: [Match Exact Row Number of Nth Largest Value In Data With Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67715755/match-exact-row-number-of-nth-largest-value-in-data-with-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

You could be thinking of:

```
=SMALL(IFERROR(ROW(A1:A5)*MATCH(A1:A5,C1,0),FALSE),ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTIF(A1:A5,C1),)))
```

Where your data start in **A1** and your compare value is in **C1**.

[image: result]

If you have **Excel 365**, this is easier:

```
=INDEX(SORT(ROW(A1:A5)*MATCH(A1:A5,C1,0)),SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(A1:A5,C1)))
```

or better yet:

```
=LET( dataRange, A1:A5,
       compareTo, C1,
       INDEX(SORT(ROW(dataRange)*MATCH(dataRange,compareTo,0)),SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(dataRange,compareTo))) )
```